# HTMLとCSSについて

Tags: html

visual studio codeで勉強のためにタイマーを作ろうとしています。
写真のようにファイルを作ったのはいいのですが、これではcssが反映されませんでした。調べていたところcssファイルをフォルダの配下に入れば反映されるとわかりましたが、なぜ反映されないのでしょうか。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「調べていたところcssファイルをフォルダの配下に入れば反映されるとわかりました」とありますがソースは何でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

CSS と HTML ファイルを個別に分けた場合、同じフォルダに保存するだけでは反映されません。
HTML の中に CSS ファイルを読み込む記述を追加する必要があります。

**例:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- 以下の行を追加 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Timer.css" />
</head>
```